# Nested p:selectManyMenu not updating (selected) value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c, mojarra

I've created a fairly complex nested dataGrid / selectManyMenu construct to enable multi-facet selection on multiple DB tables represented each by their own view model. The Basic idea was to create a fully dynamic facet panel to interactively filter search results in multiple dataTables.

**Environment**

- PrimeFaces 5.2 (community)
- PrimeFaces Sentinel 1.2
- Mojarra 2.2.8
- Weblogic 12c (12.1.3)

**Observations**

1. The `f:selectItems` in `p:selectManyMenu` are displayed correctly in filterPanel for **all** viewModel/facetContainer combinations
2. If I select items from the first viewModel in `#{basicSearchView.viewModels}` everything works perfectly fine, hence `#{facetContainer.selectedFacets}` for the corresponding facetContainer is updated
3. If I select items from the second viewModel in `#{basicSearchView.viewModels}` the `#{facetContainer.selectedFacets}` for the corresponding facetContainer is **not** updated
4. If I swap the order of viewModels the behavior changes accordingly (no selected items for the viewModel that was OK in the first place, everything fine with the defunct one from before)
5. The problems seems to be related to the order by which items are added to facetGrid

**UI Sketch**

```
filterPanel
---------------------------------------------------------------
| ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- |
| |  ViewModel 1    | |   ViewModel 2   | |   ViewModel n   | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| |  FacetField 1.1 | |  FacetField 2.1 | |  FacetField n.1 | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| |  FacetField 1.2 | |  FacetField 2.2 | |  FacetField n.2 | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | | Facet  (count)  | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
| |       ...       | |       ...       | |       ...       | |
| |-----------------| |-----------------| |-----------------| |
```

**Relevant XHTML section**

```
<p:outputPanel id="filterPanel">                     
  <p:dataGrid id="typeGrid" var="viewModel" value="#{basicSearchView.viewModels}" rows="1" 
     columns="#{basicSearchView.viewModels.size()}" style="border:none;" styleClass="lh-dgrid-column">
   <p:column>                                  
     <p:panel id="facetPanel" header="#{viewModel.modelName}">
       <p:dataGrid id="facetGrid" var="facetContainer" value="#{viewModel.facetContainers}" rows="#{viewModel.facetContainers.size()}" 
         columns="1" style="border:none;" emptyMessage="No facets found">                               
          <h:outputText value="#{facetContainer.fieldHeader}" styleClass="FontBold Fs14 hardblue"/>
         <p:selectManyMenu id="facetSelectMenu" value="#{facetContainer.selectedFacets}" converter="#{facetBeanConverter}" 
           showCheckbox="true">
           <f:selectItems value="#{facetContainer.availableFacets}" var="facet" itemLabel="#{facet.facetName} (#{facet.facetCount})" 
             itemValue="#{facet}" />
           <p:ajax update="contentForm:tabView contentForm:overviewMap"/>               
         </p:selectManyMenu>
       </p:dataGrid>
     </p:panel>
   </p:column>
  </p:dataGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
```

**Nested type hierarchy**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class BasicSearchView {

  List<ViewModel> viewModels;

  // Add managed viewModels to list
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class ViewModel {
  //...
  List<FacetContainer> facetContainers;
}

// POJO
class FacetContainer {
  //...
  String fieldHeader;
  List<FacetBean> availableFacets;
  List<FacetBean> selectedFacets;
}

// POJO
class FacetBean {
  //...
  String facetName;
  String facetCount;
}
```

Hope this describes the problem appropriately...